# How does VL_SIFT from vlfeat.org work?

Tags: sift, vlfeat

I am new to VLfeat implementation of SIFT in Matlab

Could someone help/teach me more about how does VL_SIFT from vlfeat.org work? I have read the following link http://www.vlfeat.org/mdoc/vl_sift.html and this document http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf but I still do not understand how it works.

Thanks
Marcus

Comment: What about it do you not understand? If you're asking for a complete re-explanation of the documentation and paper, that's not well-suited for a stackexchange question. But, if you have a more focused question, that would be better.

Answer (score 2):

One of the best resources on this method is indeed the original paper: 
[**Distinctive Image Features from Scale-Invariant Keypoints**, David G. Lowe, *International Journal of Computer Vision*](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf)

The more you read it the more details you will find. It is an exceptionally good self-contained paper but you need to read it very carefully. It is full of information.